# Web scraping data from an interactive chart

Tags: python, svg, charts, web-scraping

Would it be possible to get the data behind the interactive chart in [this webpage](http://index.baidu.com/?tpl=trend&word=%B2%CD%B9%DD) (sorry, website requires login)?

When I hover over the chart with a mouse, the data shows up, but how do I get that data?

Here's an extract of the HTML source code from that website:

```
<svg height="460" version="1.1" width="1037" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; left: -0.5px;">
<desc>Created with Raphaël 2.1.0</desc>
<defs>

<path style="" fill="none" stroke="#f1f1f1" d="M20,130L1017,130M20,159.66666666666666L1017,159.66666666666666M20,189.33333333333331L1017,189.33333333333331M20,219L1017,219M20,248.66666666666666L1017,248.66666666666666M20,278.3333333333333L1017,278.3333333333333M20,308L1017,308">
<path style="" fill="none" stroke="#f1f1f1" d="M295.0344827586207,130L295.0344827586207,337.66666666666663M295.0344827586207,365L295.0344827586207,415M535.6896551724138,130L535.6896551724138,337.66666666666663M535.6896551724138,365L535.6896551724138,415M776.3448275862069,130L776.3448275862069,337.66666666666663M776.3448275862069,365L776.3448275862069,415M1017,130L1017,337.66666666666663M1017,365L1017,415">
<path style="" fill="none" stroke="#cccccc" d="M17,337.66666666666663L1018,337.66666666666663">
<path style="" fill="none" stroke="#cccccc" d="M17,365L1018,365">
<rect x="20" y="130" width="997" height="207.66666666666666" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ff0000" stroke="none" style="opacity: 0;" opacity="0">
<path style="" fill="none" stroke="#6e87d7" d="M20,281.030303030303L54.37931034482759,316.6902356902357L88.75862068965517,318.78787878787875L123.13793103448276,318.78787878787875L157.51724137931035,318.78787878787875L191.89655172413794,312.4949494949495L226.27586206896552,285.2255892255892L260.65517241379314,312.4949494949495L295.0344827586207,314.59259259259255L329.41379310344826,316.6902356902357L363.7931034482759,297.8114478114478L398.1724137931035,318.78787878787875L432.55172413793105,335.56902356902356L466.9310344827586,293.61616161616155L501.3103448275862,276.8350168350168L535.6896551724138,272.6397306397306L570.0689655172414,274.7373737373737L604.448275862069,272.6397306397306L638.8275862068965,216.00336700336698L673.2068965517242,216.00336700336698L707.5862068965517,239.07744107744105L741.9655172413793,281.030303030303L776.344827586207,144.68350168350165L810.7241379310345,245.37037037037032L845.1034482758621,239.07744107744105L879.4827586206897,247.46801346801345L913.8620689655172,245.37037037037032L948.2413793103449,245.37037037037032L982.6206896551724,207.61279461279457L1017,163.56228956228955" stroke-width="2">
<path style="" fill="none" stroke="#f1f1f1" d="M20,390L1017,390M20,415L1017,415">
<path style="opacity:
```

There are many many more of these `path` elements, which I didn't paste here.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source code for this webpage?
On a different note: I see no graph, but am confronted with what looks like a login-screen. I don't see what you're apparently seeing.

Comment: yes i have. It has stuff I've never seen before.

Comment: Then it's a good idea to look into the language that makes these data appear when hovering over them. Nowadays, those are usually javascript and/or some jQuery magic. In any case, I still don't see this chart you're talking about. Can you make sure that the link you gave is correct and not dependant on a login?

Comment: I apologize. It does require a login. I inspected the element with firebug and did manage to find `Created with Raphaël 2.1.0`. Just googled it, seems like javascript. thanks for the help.

Comment: We'd have to see the source code to answer that in a specific way. Otherwise we can only guess and my guess would then be that the data itself is hidden in the myriad of linked javascript files in an array, similar to what is done with highcharts, another javascript plotting library. So it would then be as easy as finding that file. Please update your question to reflect the source code for this page.

Comment: I'm going to paste some stuff, not sure if it the correct source code.

Comment: @Oliver W. Could you help me please I am facing a similar problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886754/scraping-data-from-a-dynamic-graph-using-pythonbeautifulsoup4/26889772?noredirect=1#comment42364150_26889772

Comment: I have a similar issue on the same website that can be access here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48110288/access-the-d-element-from-an-svg-object-with-casperjs. Any healp would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to parse that information (and guessing from your tags, you'll want to do this in python). However, having had a quick look at the [Raphael documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/), I'm fairly sure you can get the data in another, quicker way: the data has to exist as a javascript array somewhere. Try looking for that first.

Eventually, from this javascript data, the SVG you've found gets generated. If you look at the [SVG Path element](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/path-element.html#path-example) description, you'll see how those `M` and `L` definitions need to be interpreted and then you should be capable of parsing those lines into the (python) dataset you like.

However, I want to state again that it is hard for us to find what you are looking for without even a picture to go on (is it a histogram, is it a linechart?). The lines that are being drawn with `L` could be all you need.

As an example, if you take that first path you've listed in a python session, you could do this:

```
svg_string = "M20,130L1017,130M20,159.66666666666666L1017,159.66666666666666M20,189.33333333333331L1017,189.33333333333331M20,219L1017,219M20,248.66666666666666L1017,248.66666666666666M20,278.3333333333333L1017,278.3333333333333M20,308L1017,308"
import re
data = [map(float, xy.split(',')) for xy in re.split('[ML]', svg_string)[1:]]
```

Remark that this only works correctly, because the `M`ove and `L`ine commands take turns in this string. But it does look like all the other paths are generated in a similar fashion (which leads me to think more strongly that the dataset is just somewhere in a javascript file you haven't looked at yet).

Finally, to obtain this sourcecode, you should look into using [urllib2](http://pymotw.com/2/urllib2/) for programmatic retrieval.

Comment: it is a line graph. thanks for looking. first time i have encountered scraping involving javascript.

Answer (score 0):

A good option for this case is combining selenium with some scraping tool like Scrapy in Python.