# Scraping graph data from a website using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrape

Is it possible to capture the graph data from a website? 
For example the website [here](http://www.fbatoolkit.com/), has a number of plots.
Is is possible to capture these data using Python code?

Comment: You want to capture only the graph? or the complete webpage is okay?

Comment: I want to get the graph data as two vectors of x and y values.

Comment: Thats tough, i thought you meant getting screenshots or take images

Comment: check this question out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23249177/web-scraping-data-from-an-interactive-chart

Comment: @HaseebR7 thanks, I looked at that but does not seem to provide an obvious path to solve my problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at the page source of the link you provided, the chart data is available directly in JSON format through the link.
http://www.fbatoolkit.com/chart_data/1414978499.87

So your scraper might want to do something like this:

```
import requests
import re

r = requests.get('http://www.fbatoolkit.com')
data_link = b'http://www.fbatoolkit.com/' + re.search(b'chart_data/[^"]*', r.content).group()
data_string = requests.get(data_link).content.decode('utf-8')
chart_data = eval(data_string.replace('window.chart_data =', '').replace(';\n',''))
```

**(Edit to explain my process for finding the link)** When I approach a problem like this, the first thing I do is view the page source, (ctrl-u in Chrome for Windows). I searched around for something related to drawing the charts, until I found the following javascript

```
  function make_containers(i){
        var chart = chart_data[i];
```

I then did a search through the source for where they defined the variable `chart_data`. I couldn't find this, but I did find the line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/chart_data/1414978499.87"></script>
```

Following this link, (you can just click on it in the view souce page in Chrome) I could see that this was a one-line piece of javascript which defines this variable. (Notice that in the last line of my example code I had to make a little change to this file to get it to evaluate in Python).

Comment: @ maxymoo: how did you find that link?

Comment: @maxmyoo: Thanks for sharing this solution with everyone! I have a similar link from which I need to extract data (http://www.dpccairdata.com/dpccairdata/display/Aallindex.php). I could read the source code and could see the actual data for one station and manually extract that to excel. However, my problem is that there are several such stations is it possible to write a python code that could help me access any station as desired. Apologies if I am not able to clearly state my problem. Any help would be much appreciated!